# Finding the distribution of a n tossed fair coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the problem:

> Consider a sequence of n tosses of a fair coin. Let X denote the number of heads, and Y denote the
>   number of isolated heads, that come up. (A head is an “isolated” head if it is immediately preceded
>   and followed by a tail, except in: position $1$ where a head is only followed by a tail, and position n
>   where the head is only preceded by a tail.) Additionally, let $X_i = 1$ if the ith coin toss results in
>   heads, and $X_i$ = 0 otherwise, i = 1, . . . , n. Similarly, $Y_j = 1$ if the jth coin toss results in an isolated
>   head, and $Y_j = 0\ otherwise, j = 1, . . . , n$.
>
> How to find the distribution of $Y |X = 2$.

Here I think $X \sim Bin(n,1/2) \ and\ Y \sim Bin(n,1/8)$. I couldn't figure out the solution of this problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If there are only two Heads then they are isolated or they are consecutive.  Not hard to get the probability of the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have $0$ isolated heads or $2$ isolated heads.

There are $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ ways to place exactly $2$ heads among the coin tosses.

Of which $n-1$ of these choices gives you non-isolated heads..

Hence

$$Pr(Y=0|X=2)=\frac{n-1}{\begin{pmatrix} n \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}}=\frac{2}{n}$$

$$Pr(Y=2|X=2)=1-Pr(Y=0|X=2)=\frac{n-2}{n}$$

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a discrete distribution, $Y=0,1,2$

- If $Y=0$, then it means two heads are next to each other. So, $P(Y=0|X=2)=\frac{n-1}{{n\choose 2}}=\frac{2}{n-2}$ (since there are n-2 ways to choose the two consecutive heads, and $n\choose 2$ ways to randomly choose 2 positions for 2 heads among n heads)
- $Y=1$ is not possible, because you cannot have one isolated coin and one coin with neighbor in the case where there are two heads. So $P(Y=1|X=2)=0$
- If $Y=2$, it means two heads are isolated, which are all cases left out. So $P(Y=2|X=2)=1-\frac{n-1}{{n\choose 2}}=\frac{n}{n-2}$